# Is there a reason that dryers aren't grounded

Tags: grounding, appliances, static-electricity

One minute ago I cried out in pain, after being electrocuted again by my clothes dryer; probably the thousandth time in my life that this has happened.

I was taking out clothes after they're dry, made the mistake of touching the metal parts of the dryer, and a jolt of static electricity went through my hand. I've had this happen in different brands of clothes dryers over the years. The one I'm using right now is a Bosch, which is supposed to be a good brand.

I'm guessing that the static electricity is generated by the clothes continually rubbing against each other, robbing each other of electrons. That's understandable, electrons will be electrons. **What I'm wondering is, why wouldn't the metal body of the dryer be connected to the mains grounding?**

Comment: I very much doubt that you were [electrocuted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocution). Please don't exaggerate.

Comment: One solution would be to stop the dryer a few minutes earlier, before the clothes are bone dry.  Even a little damp will leave them conductive enough not to build up a static charge.  You'll save money as well.  But you do have to let the clothes air for a while before putting them away.

Answer (score 3):

The metal body of the appliance **is** connected to ground.

The problem is that the clothes are charging you with respect to ground as you unload them. When you touch something grounded, then a large current flows to ground through your finger. You have a relatively large capacitance to ground, many 10s of pF, which stores quite enough energy at a few kV or 10s of kV for the discharge to be felt through your fingertips.

There are several things you can do about this.

As this is an electronics engineering site, the first thing to mention is what airline companies do to prevent the same problem, which is a discharge between the airplane and the fuel bowser, two large conductive objects on insulating tyres. You obviously do not want a spark between the fuel nozzle and the plane fuel filler! Before refuelling is started, a grounding lead is attached between them, to equalise their potentials.

Use an ESD strap, grounded to the drier, when you unload your clothes. Although each item of clothing will carry a small charge, the energy that's released by each small zap of the clothes to you will be too small to be felt. As the clothes are not conductive, you only get the charge from the tiny area in contact with your hand. The problem with the drier shock you describe is that you are conductive, and the shock you feel is the entire charge that was transferred to you, going all at once.

ESD straps are useful as well when you're working with static sensitive components. Remember you can kill a component with voltages and energies far too low to be noticed, even by your fingertips.

Another method is to anticipate that you will have been charged by the clothes, and discharge yourself by the knuckles to the drier before touching the door with your fingertips. This takes some anticipation, but you will learn fast. Knuckles have an order of magnitude or two less sensitivity than fingertips to an electric shock

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my mind around this, I'm definitely not an electrician. You said "You have a relatively large capacitance to ground." From what I remember about capacitors, they are basically two huge sheets, close together but not touching, where negative and positive charges can get real close to each other because of their attraction, but not touch each other. 
Is this what's happening between me and the ground? If so what are the sheets?

Comment: @RamRachum You are one "sheet", the ground the other. The "not touching" means not _electrically_ touching (i.e. not conducting)... many capacitors have a (non-conductive) solid/gel between the plates: there doesn't have to be an air-gap, just an "electrical" gap.

Comment: @TripeHound I find two things weird about this explanation: My feet aren't that big, and the distance between them and the ground is probably around 2cm, which is the thickness of the shoe's sole plus the sock. Isn't that a huge distance in capacitor terms?

Comment: What's probably more important than there being a capacitance to ground is that you are (largely) _insulated_ from ground. Therefore the accumulated charge from extracting many pieces of clothing will continually build-up until you happen to touch the dryer, when it all discharge at once.

Comment: A capacitor is two conductors separated by an insulator, for instance a human body, and all the earthed metal around you. It doesn't really matter what shape they are. The larger area of conductor, and the smaller the distance between them, the larger the capacitance. If you had bare feet on a concrete or bare wood floor, there would not be the insulation there, and you would not have this problem. With rubber-soled footwear or plastic floor covering, you have the insulation.

Answer (score 0):

The metal body of the dryer **has to be grounded**. If this is not the case the machine could be lethal in case of malfunction - specially the heating elements tend to break and the live potential becomes shorted to the metal casing. So the grounding is an essential safety feature.

Another story is whether is about static discharge. The clothes are insulators and static charge is produced by rubbing, these charges can't discharge since the cloth is not conducting. When you touch it, the charge is discharged trough your body into the ground while you are touching the metal part of the machine, which is supposedly grounded.

Comment: "these charges can't discharge since the cloth is not conducting" The clothes are directly touching the dryer body. Isn't that enough for the electrons to flow out? What is my hand doing that the dryer body not doing?

Comment: The charge is split into positive and negative zones, "lakes". The discharge happen when zones of different charges are connected with a conductor. So only the part of the cloth that touches the metal drum can be discharged, the rest charge located in the interior can't move and it is waiting for you to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

What they said.

**May work:**

If there is some time since the dryer was running, try turning it back on on cold for maybe 20 seconds. Distributing the clothes so they brush against the metal body MAY help.

**Will work with due care:**

Either obtain an antistatic earth strap or (much cheaper) obtain a 1 megohm resistor with a wire connected to each end.  Connect one wire (clip OK) to a part of the dryer's metal body.  Then:

- Open the dryer door but DO NOT touch the dryer body or the clothes.
- Wearing insulating shoes or stand on an insulating mat (eg rubber sheet).
- Hold the other wire end and reach into the open dryer and "stir" the clothes by hand being sure not to touch any metal dryer body parts.

The static charge should pass from the clothes to you then via the 1 megohm resistor to ground. This should ensure charge discharge at a slow enough rate to not cause pain - but still very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that the body of the dryer is grounded but the rotating drum might not be. Perhaps the drum is supported on rubber mounts and is driven by a rubber drive belt. It would be easy for the drum to develop a substantial **static** charge, which will not kill you. And it would be easy to discharge that static by touching the drum and body at the same time.

The purpose of grounding the body is to protect you in the event that a live mains wire gets shorted to the body. If you get static shocks when you touch the **body** that is a good sign.

Answer (score -1):

So far the dryer has metal it is advisable that metal get  earthed in other to safe gaurd any unforeseen circumstances